# Queues in IOT Hub

Tags: azure, queue, azure-iot-hub

I have the following situation in Azure IOT Hub:

- Script sends message to device queue. Listening with device explorer: Succes
- Script listens for message to device queue. Sending with device explorer: Succes

This problem arises:

- Script listens for message to device queue. Other script sends message to device queue: Listener does not receive the message.

So, it works well using the device explorer tool. But with the scripts only, the listener does not receive.

I hope someone might be able to help me with this issue.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: The code is in this repository: https://github.com/encrypted90/IoTHub-Connector

Comment: For testing the device explorer can be used: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer

Answer (score 0):

There might be two possible problems on your side:

a) [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer) shows messages only from one device. If you have two separate device clients, you have to select another one.

b) But it's possible that you send and receive on two separate scripts with one deviceId (clientId) - it might be the problem.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I will look at your problems and do some further research, hopefully solving this issue.